# Disposing a StringBuilder object

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management, memory-leaks, string

How does one effectively dispose a `StringBuilder` object? If an user generates multiple reports in a single sitting, my app ends up using a huge amount of memory.

I've read in a few sites online that the follow may help:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000000);

// loop goes here adding lots of stuff to sb

exampleObject.Text = sb.ToString();

sb.Length = 0;
```

Does the last line really help? Any other way of dealing with this?

NB: This does not really stop my users from continuing to use the application. I'm just wondering if there is a way of avoiding redundant memory usage.

Comment: taking out the 1000000 might help

Comment: How? Pre-allocating memory helped a lot. Letting StringBuilder constantly resize was slowing things down quite a bit.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No, a `StringBuilder` is a purely managed resource. You should just get rid of all references to it. Everything else is taken care of by the garbage collector:

```
StringBuilder sb = ...;
// ... do work
sb = null; // or simply let it go out of scope.
```

In .NET, there's no deterministic `delete` (like C++, where you free up memory allocated to a single object.) Only GC can free memory. By forfeiting all references to an object, you'll let GC be able to deallocate the object if it wants to. You can force a garbage collection by calling the `System.GC.Collect` method. However, it's not recommended to manipulate with GC unless you really know what you are doing. GC is smart. It's rarely beneficial to force it.

Comment: adding a GC.Collect() is perfectly valid if memory utilization within the app is excessive to the point of causing problems with out of memory exhaustion. .Net garbage collection will automatically clean it up when you are trying to allocate additional memory and the o/s is starved, or during its next cycle. Usually you do not need it unless your app is very performance driven.

Answer (score 4):

If you are generating many reports, you could consider re-using a single StringBuilder instead of allocating a new one for each report.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the 'excessive memory usage' is a problem, I would leave it as it is and not worry about it.

.NET is in most cases smart enough to avoid doing a garbage collection if you have enough memory available.

Comment: I am facing a problem where I think I identified a lot of unmanaged memory ~4GB  being used over time on one of our API's that uses a lot of StringBuilder to build custom queries. I used dotMemoery to try and help me find a source of the problem because in code it looks OK. I do in-fact find a ton of stringbuilder, string and dictionaries living in unmanaged memory? And never get GC'ed. The string are these queires. For context 1 query can be 2mb in size so yea... it eventually creeps up to 4GB and we cant work out why and how to dispose of this?

Comment: If they are not GC'ed, it means one of two things: GC is broken (I have never heard of this happening in such a case but I try to keep an open mind) or you are somehow still referencing them. The most likely reason is the second. Is your code open on the net for pair review?

Comment: Yea.. probably reference issue or static misuse? Sorry code is private. I was just doing some more profiling and the managed code GC works fine, constantly under 200mb but the unmaged code grows and grows and grows... its running behind IIS so who knows? Is there any way to find out whats in the unmaged memory?

Comment: Probably is, but outside of my expertise.

Comment: Im going to try going down memory dump lane and see if I come out with my sanity in tact 